# How to create dsl script for a pipeline job for property - Build after other projects are built

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

Can you please help me in creating the dsl script for a pipeline job which has got the property - Build after other projects are built. Let the other project be Project A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `upstream` API of Jenkins Job DSL.

Please look into this for a sample example:

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-triggers-upstream